# Gaussian-Like integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, improper-integrals

What is the integral of this?

$$\int_0^\infty xe^{-(ax^2+bx)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty xe^{-(ax^2+bx)}~dx$$

$$=\int_0^\infty xe^{-a\left(x^2+\frac{bx}{a}\right)}~dx$$

$$=\int_0^\infty xe^{-a\left(x^2+\frac{bx}{a}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)}~dx$$

$$=e^\frac{b^2}{4a}\int_0^\infty xe^{-a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2}~dx$$

$$=e^\frac{b^2}{4a}\int_\frac{b}{2a}^\infty\left(x-\dfrac{b}{2a}\right)e^{-ax^2}~dx$$

$$=e^\frac{b^2}{4a}\int_\frac{b}{2a}^\infty xe^{-ax^2}~dx-\dfrac{be^\frac{b^2}{4a}}{2a}\int_\frac{b}{2a}^\infty e^{-ax^2}~dx$$

$$=e^\frac{b^2}{4a}\int_\frac{b}{2a}^\infty xe^{-ax^2}~dx-\dfrac{be^\frac{b^2}{4a}}{2a}\int_\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}^\infty e^{-x^2}~d\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt a}\right)$$

$$=e^\frac{b^2}{4a}\left[-\dfrac{e^{-ax^2}}{2a}\right]_\frac{b}{2a}^\infty-\dfrac{be^\frac{b^2}{4a}}{2a\sqrt a}\int_\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}^\infty e^{-x^2}~dx$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{2a}-\dfrac{b\sqrt\pi e^\frac{b^2}{4a}}{4a\sqrt a}\text{erfc}\left(\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt a}\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

$$
ax^{2} + bx = a\left[\left(x-\frac{b}{2a}\right)^{2} - \frac{b^{2}}{4a^{2}}\right]
$$
make the substitution 
$$
z = \sqrt{2a}\left(x -\frac{b}{2a}\right)
$$
you will end up with an integral like this
$$
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{b^{2}}{4a}}}{2a}\int \left(z-\frac{b}{\sqrt{2a}}\right)\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{z^{2}}{2}}dz
$$
or if we split it up
$$
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{b^{2}}{4a}}}{2a}\left[\int^{\infty}_{0} z\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{z^{2}}{2}}dz -\frac{b}{\sqrt{2a}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{z^{2}}{2}}dz \right] = \int_{0}^{\infty}x\mathrm{e}^{-\left(ax^{2} + bx\right)}dx
$$
at this point you can make use of 
$$
\int z\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{z^{2}}{2}} = \int -\frac{d}{dz}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{z^{2}}{2}} = -\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{z^{2}}{2}}
$$

the rest you can probably do. Any errors, or need further help comment :).

$\textbf{Edit:}$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{b^{2}}{4a}}}{2a}\left[1 - \frac{b}{\sqrt{2a}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\right]
$$

you can simplify.

$\textbf{Edit 2:}$
As pointed out by @harrypeter i forgot to choose the appropriate limits for the integral. If one does use the correct limits you will achieve the same result.

Comment: sorry but can you solve it till the end...I also think you made when you did split the integral...please check it once more.

Comment: I made the changes to the answer to solve it to the end. You were right that I  made a mistake with separating the integral.

Answer (score 1):

The general method is to "complete the square" in the exponent, that is, write
$e^{-(ax^2+bx)}$ as $e^{-(\alpha x - \beta)^2}\cdot e^{\gamma}$ for suitable
choice of $\alpha, \beta$, and $\gamma$ so as to get the exponential term
looking like a Gaussian density function. Then, use the fact that $-xe^{-x^2}$
has antiderivative $e^{-x^2/2}$.