# Method for integrating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} dx$?

Tags: integration

As part of a proof on deriving the mean and variance of the standard normal distribution I came across the following integral -

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} dx$$

which integrates to

$$-e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\mid_{-\infty}^\infty$$

I don't know what method is being used to perform this integration?

Comment: It is of the form $\int f^\prime f$. Derive $x\mapsto e^{-x^2/2}$ to see why.

Comment: You're missing a minus sign (not that it matters for the result). One just uses the fact that $$\frac{d}{dx} e^{-x^2/2} = -xe^{-x^2/2}.$$

Comment: here is one i made earlier http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685046/gaussian-like-integral/685066#685066

Comment: @DanielFischer Would you consider it obvious that the initial function integrates to that equation though? It's obvious when you have $F(x)$ that it differentiates to $f(x)$ but given just the $f(x)$ it doesn't seem obvious to me that it integrates to $F(x)$...maybe I just need to get used to seeing more of them...

Comment: It takes a bit of practice, of course, but after a while, yes, that is obvious. Depending on the amount of practice, the border where things are obvious is at different degrees of complication, but for such integrands, it doesn't take long.

Comment: Guess and check method.

Answer (score 2):

This is $u$-substitution.  If you let $u=-\frac{x^2}{2}$, then $du=-x\,dx$.  The integral becomes
$$
\int -e^u\, du.
$$

Comment: Just noticed when I tried u-substition that I had left out the $2$ in the denominator when writing down the formula, no wonder it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using the change of variables $u=x^2/2$ and $du=xdx$
$$
\int xe^{-x^2/2} dx = \int e^{-u} du = -e^{-u}
$$
And re-substituting you get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider, for nonnegative integer $k$, $$I(k) = \int_{x=0}^\infty f(k;x) \, dx, \quad f(k;x) = x^k e^{-x^2/2}.$$  For $k = 0$, we have $I(0) = \sqrt{\pi/2}$, which we can prove in a number of ways, such as considering a double integral of the form $$\int_{x=0}^\infty \int_{y=0}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} \, dy \, dx.$$  For $k = 1$, we have by the substitution $$u = x^2/2, \quad du = x \, dx$$ the result $$I(1) = \int_{u=0}^\infty e^{-u} \, du = \lim_{L \to \infty} \left[ -e^{-u} \right]_{u=0}^L = 0 - (-1) = 1.$$  For general $k$, we use integration by parts with the choice $u = x^{k-1}$, $du = (k-1)x^{k-2} \, dx$, $dv = x e^{-x^2/2} \, dx$, $v = -e^{-x^2/2}$, the choice of $v$ being informed by our earlier calculation of $I(1)$.  Then $$\begin{align*} I(k) &= \lim_{L \to \infty} \left[ -x^{k-1} e^{-x^2/2} \right]_{x=0}^L + (k-1) \int_{x=0}^\infty x^{k-2} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx \\ &= (k-1) I(k-2).\end{align*}$$  Therefore, we have $$\begin{align*} I(2n) &= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \prod_{j=1}^n (2j-1) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}, \\ I(2n+1) &= \prod_{j=1}^n 2j = 2^n n!. \end{align*}$$  Since these are finite, we can now consider symmetry:  for even $k = 2n$, $f(2n;x) = f(2n;-x)$, hence $$\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty f(2n;x) \, dx = 2I(2n).$$  For odd $k = 2n+1$, $f(2n+1;x) = -f(2n+1;x)$ and $$\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty f(2n+1;x) \, dx = 0.$$

Comment: It is interesting that in your proof of the general setting, there is no care taken for the existence of the general integral for various $k$'s that you admonished me on for my solution. You use the symmetry of the integrand just like I did. Hmm, I wonder why there is this glaring instance of a double standard. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure why you wrote that:  the above clearly shows the explicit evaluation of the integral over $[0,\infty)$ for positive integers $k$, which **does** show existence.  I wrote, "Since these are finite, we can now consider symmetry."  Your answer (which I upvoted, btw) did not show that the integral over half the real line was convergent.

Comment: I am referring to the second line where you define $I(k)$. To be rigorous to the standard set before, you have to show the existence of the limit to infinity even before your write down the improper integral expression.

Comment: No, that is not correct.  Of course you can write down $I(k)$:  the integrand $f(k;x)$ has no singularities and the limiting behavior of $f(k;x)$ at $\infty$ is not in question.  As I explained in my comment on your answer, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(k;x) = 0$ but that in itself does not prove $\int_0^\infty f(k;x) \, dx$ exists.  Convergence of the *integrand* to zero is a necessary but not sufficient condition for convergence of the *integral*.

Comment: I am confused. Your last sentence is exactly my point, and is what I am protesting about your proof being not rigorous. However one proves the integrability, you have NOT done it. Are you saying, to be rigorous, you do not need to prove the existence of the integral $\int_0^\infty f(k,x)dx$ before you define $I(k)=\int_0^\infty f(k,x)dx$? If you can, what is then the basis on which you criticized my solution earlier?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my previous phrase "the limit to infinity". I am not referring to the limit of $f(k,x)$ but the limit of the integral $\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^y f(k,x)dx$. You need to show the existence of this limit.

Comment: My proof is completely rigorous, whether or not you recognize it to be so.  Until you can precisely articulate what it is that you find deficient in my answer, I have nothing more to add to this comment thread.

Comment: That is one obstinate response. Let me quote your very own comment not long ago to articulate what I find deficient in your solution "one can't just claim that the integral exists--we have to SHOW it formally." You have not shown the existence of the integrals formally. You failed to uphold the standard that you hold others to. That is what I called double standard. It is a bit ironic, isn't it?

Comment: You are more than welcome to fill in the gaps that you perceive to exist in my exposition for yourself.  I encourage you to post exactly what you think is missing.  Unless you can furnish some actual mathematics instead of continuing to make vague claims and accusations, there is nothing else I can say. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact the integrand is an odd function to see the integral on the negative $x$ axis cancels that on the positive $x$ axis and the integral vanishes. This way, you do not even need to be able to analytically integrate the indefinite integral.

Comment: You have to be very careful with this but this is a reasonable approach.

Comment: It is a way (straightforward) to get that all odd moments are zero (although not exactly what the OP asked).

Comment: @CameronWilliams: What is there to be especially careful with? The integral exists because of the rapid decay of the integrand at infinity.

Comment: @Hansen:  that is precisely what we need to be careful about.  One can't just claim that the integral exists--we have to *show* it formally.  An integrand can have $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ but its improper integral over $[0,\infty)$ is not bounded; e.g., $f(x) = 1/x$.  So "rapid decay" needs to be rigorously explained.  That was all that was meant.

Comment: I think convergence is what Cameron was referring to. Of course you're right that the integral exists, but it seems to me that the easiest way to show that is to do the u substitution. So you're not really saving yourself any work.

Comment: The integral is improper at both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ and the limits must be taken individually so the odd-ness of the integrand doesn't help much on the surface (but there are ways around this).

Comment: You guys are right about being careful in rigor. @CameronWilliams: The integral is proper at infinity. Because say, $xe^{-x^2}<\frac{1}{x^4}$ or $x^2 > 4 \ln x$ for large enough $x$. The latter is integrable at infinity.